# How to do short circuit print in C?

Tags: c, if-statement, printf, expression, short-circuiting

Hello everybody: I've an expression like this:

```
if (a == 1) {
   printf("hello\n");
}
```

Is there a way to do something like that?

```
 a== 1 && printf("hello\n");
```

It's called short-circuit expression, but I don't know anything about it. Does it exist in C? How to do it.

Comment: if you have  `if(a && b)`, expression `b` is not evaluated if `a` yields `false`. This is short circuit. However, it is a bad design if any of your expression has side effects

Comment: Yes, this works in C: https://godbolt.org/z/TKc55Td6T Doesn't mean you *should* do it. An `if` statement will generally be more clear in most cases.

Comment: It's valid C code, just do it. I do not understand what you are asking. Anyway `"` is missing in `printf`.

Comment: Don't do this even if it's valid C code. Focus on readability unless you're participating in an obfuscated C contest.

Comment: You have also the ternary operator way : `a==1?printf("hello\n"):0;`, its readability is not very good anyway here. A simple `if` seems here the most efficient and readable. Just see @alagner answer, from my pov, inside ternary is less readable.

Comment: Both of your examples are the exact same thing. a better example would be with two things, e.g. `a == 1 && b == 2 && whatever` versus `if (a== 1 && b == 2) { whatever }`
in which case they would be exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out in comments, doing `a == 1 && printf("hallo\n");` will indeed work as I believe you intended, i.e. "hallo" will only be printed if the condition is true, if a is 1 in this case. The short answer is yes, short-circuit expressions do exist in C.

This can be easily determined by compiling and running the code, which is the recommended way if you're just exploring how the language works. However, if the question is, *"is it good practice to use it to decide when to print?"*, many people would say **no**. It's best to stick to more readable, and therefore more maintainable code, with the `if` statement in your example.

Answer (score 0):

A word of warning here:
it works as long as the expression to the right hand side of `&&` returns sth convertible to boolean, e.g. printf in this case returns an int. It is valid C code, true, but seems a code smell to me and many people would complain during the review.

Note also, that sth like this:

```c
void foo(char*)
{
//whatever
}

int main(void)
{
    int a = 1;
    a == 1 && foo("abc");
}
```

is not going to to work and you'll have to use some tricks, e.g. with comma operator:
`a == 1 && (foo("abc"),1);`

Thus, for the sake of maintainability, you might want to use some other construct, e.g. the ternary operator:
`printf(a==1?"Hello\n":"");`
which is not exactly equivalent, but might (or might not) work better in your particular case.

EDIT:
as per comment below:

It is true, that passing conditional input to printf's format string can be considered a bad practice, especially in more complicated cases as rids one of compiler diagnostics related to printf's input params.
@chqrlie suggested just using a one-liner if: `if(a==1)printf("hello\n");` which is fine as long as coding conventions allow it. Sometimes they don't.

If so, the somewhat cleaner ternary version is this: `printf("%s",a==1? "Hello\n":"");`. Please note however this is all matter of coding conventions/programmer's and reviewer's taste/linter settings/insert-your-source-of-good-practices-here. Thus, one can most likely skin this cat in way more ways, and the list is definitely not exhaustive.

Comment: Good answer, yet I would not advise nor even suggest `printf(a==1?"Hello\n":"");` that defeats the compiler's ability to type check `printf`'s variable arguments. A more palatable  one-liner alternative is `if (a == 1) printf("hello\n);`

Comment: @chqrlie how about `printf("%s", condition?"hello\n":"");`? I would oftentimes work with code where `one-liner if` was a bigger no-no that the question mark, so it might be just my taste/habit. But granted, passing just bare string to printf is not that good either.

Comment: Calling `printf("")` costs cpu cycles. Not calling it doesn't. It's as simple as that.